# Cartesian product of string[] with itself without duplicate/clone directly in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, shortcut, cartesian-product

Please excuse my lack of better terminology. I have a `string[]` and I'd like to get the product of a catesian join with itself for later to put in a dictionary. However, I'd like all possible combinations *except* when there is a clone/duplicate key.

```
string[] array1 = { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
string[][] arrayOfArrays = array1.SelectMany(left => array1, (left, right) => new string[] { left, right }).ToArray();
```

Will obtain a `string[][]` from all possible combinations yielding as each element:

```
aa aa
aa bb
aa cc
bb aa
bb bb
bb cc
cc aa
cc bb
cc cc
```

What I'm trying to understand here is what is the joining called when you have the result like this:

```
aa bb
aa cc
bb aa
bb cc
cc aa
cc bb
```

That way when I make my dictionary I don't have to go in with a for loop and take out those keys to the value pair.  If you have a demonstration of this in a 1-liner or lambda I'd love to see it as I'm trying to understand more about this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it has a name, but you can use a `Where` clause to filter out those matching values.

```
string[][] arrayOfArrays =
    array1.SelectMany(left => array1, (left, right) => new string[] { left, right })
          .Where(x => x[0] != x[1])
          .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Although I am wondering what the name is now.  In case I have to look this operation up again in a different language.