# Jagged Array[][] find all selected elements in column

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array:

```
int[][] loadData

     a1
o1 | 3  1 5 4 3 3 1
o2 | 1  4 1 2 2 1 0
o3 | 4  4 5 4 4 3 1
o4 | 2  3 4 4 5 4 1
o5 | 3  3 5 2 5 5 1
o6 | 3  3 3 1 5 2 0
o7 | 2  5 3 5 1 2 1
o8 | 4  5 4 4 4 1 0 // this is my jagged array without o1 and a1 I use them for example
```

I want find all elements in column `a1` who have number 3. I tried to mix the code but with no effect.

for example for 3 in column `a1`:

```
Dictionary<int, int?>[] matrix = new Dictionary<int, int?>[8];
matrix[0].Add(1, 3);
matrix[0].Add(5, 3);
matrix[0].Add(6, 3);

var x = Array.FindAll(loadData, a => Enumerable.Range(0, s)
                                   .Select(j => loadData[j][0]));`
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you mean by "find all."

If you want to find and count the number of rows, you can just

```
var count = array.Count( a => a[0] == 3 );
```

If you want to output the row numbers, it's a little trickier, since you have to pass the row number through before you apply the `Where` portion, or else the original row number will be lost.

```
var indexes = array.Select
( 
    (a, i) => 
    new { RowNumber = i, Value = a[0]} 
)
.Where( n => n.Value == 3 )
.Select( r => r.RowNumber )
```

You could also just flatten the array:

```
var flatList = array.SelectMany
(
    (array, row) => 
    array.Select
    (
        (element,column) => 
        new { Row = row, Column = column, Value = element } 
    )
);
```

...and then query it like a flat table:

```
var indexes = flatList.Select
( 
    element => element.Column = 0 && element.Value == 3 
)
.Select( a => a.Row );
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I think you may be looking for using linq is utilizing a `.Where` clause on a `SelectMany` statement.  I had a question posted that was kind of similar although i was converting it into a string[][] array.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784942/7813290